# Typescript React types not recognised when compiling

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert an application to React with typescript. I had it running correctly in plain ES2015. But now that I've added typescript to the picture, gulp throws errors when trying to compile my `.tsx` file:

```
error TS2339: Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'App'.
```

Even a stripped down test component fails with:

```
error TS2605: JSX element type 'App' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'App' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, refs
```

```
import * as React from "../libs/noinject/react.development";
import * as ReactDOM from "../libs/noinject/react-dom.development";

interface State {foo: string}
export class App extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  state: State
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: 'bar',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.foo}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app-root'));
});
```

Clearly, the typescript compiler is not recognising the `React.Component` type. I am using `gulp-typescript` to compile, with the following compiler options:

```
{
    'lib': ['ES2018', 'DOM'],
    'target': 'es6',
    'module': 'none',
    'moduleResolution': 'node',
    'jsx': 'react',
    'types': [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
    ],
  }
```

node modules `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` are installed and clearly being used, since removing them immediately causes the TS compilation step to fail complaining about the types not being found.

Note that I also get the squiggly red underline in vscode intellisense with the same error (`Type 'App' is missing the following properties...`).

What gives?

Comment: Can you try change your typescript.json/option to modules:"commonjs" and not "none"?

Comment: I've tried 'commonjs' and 'ES6' - no dice :(

Answer (score 1):

I got your setup to work by adding a `tsconfig.json` to the root directory with the following contents:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": [
      "react",
      "react-dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Then, in the `gulpfile.js`, I had the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var project = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('./index.tsx')
        .pipe(project())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/"));
});
```

Testing with `gulp-typescript` and the other code and packages you said you had, I was able to get this to compile and create an `index.js` file in the `dist/` folder.

Comment: Thanks - upvoting for your efforts ;)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was I was importing React from the .js file, when I needed just to import "react" which typescript 2+ knows how to find inside the `node_modules/@types`. In other words, the lines:

```
import * as React from "../libs/noinject/react.development";
import * as ReactDOM from "../libs/noinject/react-dom.development";
```

should be:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```